# What does "wander into" mean?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, birds-of-prey

Black Mask says to Mr Keo:

> Black Mask: I'm not talking superficial partnerships. I'm talking you
>   and me having each other's backs. The Golden Lions can't just **wander 
>   into** Gotham National Bank. I can. Loans, liquidity, laundering. Look,
>   if you bring your boys into the fold, there are no limits to what we
>   could achieve together.

I know the Golden Lions have operated in Gotham for nearly 100 years.
So what does "wander into" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is more appropriate to English Language exchange, but 'Wander in' means to walk in casually.

As per Webster's definition;

> Definition of wander
>   intransitive verb
>
> 1a: to move about without a fixed course, aim, or goal
>
> 1b: to go idly about : RAMBLE

In this instance it is being made clear that the Golden Lions turning up at the bank will be noticed.